# How change android app locale programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the correct solution in 2023 to programmatically change the application's locale? I've tried different ways, but nothing worked for me.
This is one of the solutions I found but it doesn't work.
object LocaleHelper {

```
fun setLocale(context: Context, language: String): Context {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        updateResources(context, language)
    } else {
        updateResourcesLegacy(context, language)
    }
}

private fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String): Context {
    val locale = Locale(language)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val configuration = Configuration(context.resources.configuration)
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
}

private fun updateResourcesLegacy(context: Context, language: String): Context {
    val locale = Locale(language)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val resources = context.resources
    val configuration = resources.configuration
    configuration.locale = locale
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
    return context
}
```

}

```
    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.setLocale(newBase, "kk"))
    }

    val newContext = LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "kk")
    ActivityCompat.recreate(this)
```

There are translations into other languages, and they are in the resources.
please tell me how to change the locale in the application

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a possible solution.

In your activity:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    val newConfiguration = Configuration(newBase?.resources?.configuration).apply {
        setLocale(Locale("kk"))
    }
 
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase?.createConfigurationContext(newConfiguration))
}
```

Don't forget to call `Activity.recreate()` if you want to switch language at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void setLanguage(Context elContexto, Locale myLocale) 
{

        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);

        Resources res = context.getResources();

        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

You call it like:

setLanguage(getApplicationContext(), new Locale("us"));

And then, reset app.